# Waiting for ajax Request using Callbacks

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel, callback

I was trying to  use callbacks to wait for Ajax request but it wouldnt work
 .can someone please tell me the logic behind callbacks and help me in-cooperate it in my laravel code.

```
         function sendImageToController(callback){
                $.ajaxSetup({
                    headers: { 'X-CSRF-Token' : $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content') } 
                    });
                $.ajax({
                    url: "{{route('HeatMap.moveToStorage')}}",
                    data: {"imgUrl":imgUrl,
                        "targetHeatMap":myMap
                },
                    type:'post',
                    success:function(response){
                        //Refresh After Creating the image
                        if(!window.location.hash) {
                            // alert('Please Wait Loading');
                                //window.location = window.location + '#loaded';
                                //window.location.reload();
                                }
                                console.log("correct");
                                console.log(response);
                            },
                    error:function(e){
                        console.log(e);
                    },
                });               
            }
```

Comment: _"but it wouldnt work"_ in what way didn't it work. Be specific, was there an error message in the console, did you not get either of the console logs from `success` or `error`?

Answer (score 0):

you need to call callback function from success and error function

```
success:function(response){
    callback(null, response);
}error:function(e){
    callback(e, null);
}
```

so it will call callback function in callback function first argument will be error and second will be result.

Comment: and do i need to define function callback?

Comment: yes you have to make a function in a argument of the function like 
your ajax function name is `sendImageToController(callback)` then you have to call like
`sendImageToController(function(err, result){
});`
in this function you have to check err and result